# Inequalities involving multiple p-norms

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

The $p$-norm of a vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, denoted $\|x\|_p$, is $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$.

**Question:** For a list $1\leq p_1<\dots<p_k$, what inequality relations are guaranteed to hold for $\|x\|_{p_1},\cdots\|x\|_{p_n}$ for any $x$, independent of $n$?

**Examples:** For $k=2$, it is known that $\|x\|_{p_1}\geq\|x\|_{p_2}$. This is tight, and there is no inequality in the other direction (other than those that depend on $n$).

For $k=3$, we obviously $\|x\|_{p_1}\geq\|x\|_{p_2}\geq\|x\|_{p_3}$ by the $k=2$ case. We can conclude one more inequality:
$$\left(\|x\|_{p_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_2}-\frac{1}{p_3}}\left(\|x\|_{p_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_3}-\frac{1}{p_1}}\left(\|x\|_{p_3}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_1}-\frac{1}{p_2}}\geq 1$$
The cyclic form of the $k=3$ inequality is potentially misleading: it only holds if $1\leq p_1<p_2<p_3$, but not if we change the order of the $p_i$. The inequality follows from applying Holder's inequality $\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_{1/a}\|g\|_{1/(1-a)}$ (for $a\leq 1$) to the vectors $f=x^b$ and $g=x^c$, where:
$$a=\frac{p_3-p_2}{p_3-p_1}\;\;\;\;b=p_1 a\;\;\;\; c=p_3(1-a) $$

The $k=3$ inequality can therefore be seen giving a lower bound on $\|x\|_{p_3}$ in terms of the other two norms. Note that no upper bound on $\|x\|_{p_3}$ that is independent of $n$ can hold, except for the trivial bound $\|x\|_{p_3}\leq \|x\|_{p_2}$. It is not hard for any $\ell_1,\ell_2$ give a sequence of vectors $x^{(i)}$ such that
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\|x\|_{p_1}=\ell_1\;\;\;\;\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\|x\|_{p_2}=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\|x\|_{p_3}=\ell_2$$

So concrete questions would be: is the $k=3$ inequality derived from Holder's inequality tight? And what can be said for $k\geq 4$?